# Next.js SEO files

Tags: next.js, seo

My app folder is like:

[image: app folder]

Now, I want to add `metadata`, `robots.txt`, `sitemap`, etc. for SEO. However, the `layout.js` and `page.js` files are client-sided, therefore I can't use functions like `generateMetaData`. What should I do at this point?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert those pages to server side. By removing use client from the top of the files. And move any client side logic to useClient components. Here's the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns)

```
export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <html  lang="en" >
      <body>
        // Provider is client side for setting up redux etc.
        <Providers>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
// Server Side
const PageHome = () => {
  return (
    <div>
       // Client side
       <PageHomeComponent />
    </div>
  )
}
export default PageHome
```